# Node.js process.kill() is not killing a child process on Windows OS

Tags: node.js, windows, process, child-process, kill

I want to kill a child process created using [`spawn`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processspawncommand-args-options) in [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/)

Its working fine on [Linux OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux)

```js
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var child = spawn('kate', {detached: true}); // to open Kate editor on linux
process.kill(child.pid);
```

On [Window 11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows) its not working

```js
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var child = spawn('notepad', {detached: true}); // to open Notepad editor on Windows
process.kill(child.pid);
```

`process.kill()` is returning `true` but process still exists.

Why `process.kill()` is not working on Windows OS to kill a child process?

Comment: What returns `process.kill` on Windows?

Comment: It's mentioned in question